# Bootstrap Datepicker date range picker not allowed to select 30th of Sept

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I have no idea why it's behaving like this so my example is simple I am using php from and to the date set up in date-range by default.

However, when they try to select to date as "30/09/2018" then they can't select that. Not sure why they can't select that.

Here is my code for date range picker from bootstrap datepicker:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group input-large date-picker input-daterange" data-date="10/11/2012" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="from" value="<?php echo date("d/m/Y",$start_date);?>">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
        to </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="to" value="<?php echo date("d/m/Y",$end_date); ?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

Issue image
[image]
[image]
If I keep to date blank without any bydefault then work fine but also get broken if I select date range and once and then try to again select date-to as 30th of sept.:
[image]

So whenever I try to select 30th of sept its automatically select 29th of sept so not sure why its doing this.

Comment: Not reproducible

Comment: what else you required

Comment: Put your code in a fiddle or in a snippet so we could run it.